# Regular expression in javascript that access decimals and numbers only

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to make regular expression which supports all below numbers,

- Max length of the number : 7
- Max length of decimal places: 2

Example:

- **Valid** : 500, 1234567, 350.75, 7500.05, 4500.3
- **Not valid** : 100.123, 12345678, 45000.25

I tried with

`<input type='number' pattern="/^\d{1,7}(\.\d{1,2})?$/"/>`

but its not satisfying the max length value.

Kindly help in this issue.

Comment: `/^(\d{1,7}|\d{1,5}\.\d|\d{1,4}\.\d{1,2})$/`

Comment: does 7 include 2 dec places or is it 7 + 2 ?

Comment: "45000.25" shouldn't be in Valid samples?

Comment: hi webduvet, 7 include decimal places

Comment: Hi Jaromanda, can you tell me the same for  max length 10 and max decimals 6. Thx

Comment: Hi Mat, its invalid number. Max number means total length of the number including '.' So 1234.67 [total 7]is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check length via lookahead.

```
               ↓               ↓       CHANGE THESE PARAMETERS
/^(?=(.[.]?){1,7}$)\d*([.]\d{1,2})?$/
  |---------------|                    LOOK-AHEAD TO CHECK LENGTH
                   |-|                 INTEGER PORTION OF NUMBER
                      |-----------|    OPTIONAL DECIMAL PORTION OF NUMBER
```

This is more easily scalable to variations of the problem such as "up to seven total digits with up to four decimal places" than other solutions are. Just replace the two characters pointed to by "CHANGE THESE PARAMETERS".

Comment: Its accepting 5 integers [ex: 12345.78]. In this case length has become 8.

Comment: My understanding of the statement of the problem was that the maximum length of seven applied to digits, not to the decimal point itself. So in this interpretation 12345.78 should be accepted, because the total number of digits is 7.

Comment: Sorry for that, but i have mentioned '45000.25' this as 'No Valid'. Max number 7 means total length of the number including '.'

Comment: Hi torazburo, i slighlty modified your answer & its working fine. /^(?=(.?){1,7}$)\d*([.]\d{1,2})?$/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this will do it for ya:

```
^(\d{1,5}\.\d{2}|\d{1,6}\.\d|\d{1,7})$
```

Anything that is 5.2 or 6.1 or 7 digits (max number of characters)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fayiqi/2/edit?js,console) for the pattern.

```
var re = /^(\d{1,7}|\d{1,6}\.\d|\d{1,5}\.\d{1,2})$/;

function validate(str) {
  return (str).match(re) !== null;
}

function assert(value, expected) {
  return value === expected;
}

console.log(
  assert(validate("1234567"), true)
);

console.log(
  assert(validate("123456.7"), true)
);

console.log(
  assert(validate("12345.67"), true)
);

console.log(
  assert(validate("1234.567"), false)
);

console.log(
  assert(validate("12345.678"), false)
);

console.log(
  assert(validate("123456.78"), false)
);

console.log(
  assert(validate("1234567.8"), false)
);

console.log(
  assert(validate("12345678"), false)
);
```

Comment: Can you extend this approach to handle the case of maximum decimal places of 10 (with a larger maximum total length, such as 15)?

Comment: No, my `re` is not scalable like that sadly. I'm not familiar with your "look ahead" approach. But I want to be. I tried out the pattern as is in my [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xefiteh/edit?js,console), but the second and third tests fail. I wasn't sure how to modify the expression to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the OPs comment that *7 include decimal places* as meaning that the decimal *point* was included. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Cool, your updated expression satisfies my [test suite](https://jsbin.com/gutacu/edit?js,console). And yours has the advantage of being scalable.

Comment: mattgreen's expression works with the [test suite](https://jsbin.com/toxola/edit?js,console) too. But is it scalable?